# how to show 'font-awesome' icon in react, gutenberg wordpress

Tags: javascript, reactjs, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I am new in programming with react and try to build a gutenberg block for wordpress.
I am try to build a testimonial block with a star rating. The stars are imported from font-awesome. Mine problem is that font-awesome isn't showing at the front-end, but is showing a string.

So creating the block you have the editor side and the front-end side.

The icons are showing in the editor side with:

```js
selectcontrolDisplay = props.attributes.testimonial.map( ( testimonial, index ) => {
                  if (testimonial.selectcontrol == 'star') {
                    return  (testimonial.selectcontrol == 'star') ? <span><i className="fas fa-star checked"></i></span> : testimonial.selectcontrol;
                  } else if (testimonial.selectcontrol == 'star2') {
                    return  (testimonial.selectcontrol == 'star2') ? <span><i className="fas fa-star checked"></i><i className="fas fa-star checked"></i></span> : testimonial.selectcontrol;
                  } else if (testimonial.selectcontrol == 'star3') {
                    return  (testimonial.selectcontrol == 'star3') ? <span><i className="fas fa-star checked"></i><i className="fas fa-star checked"></i><i className="fas fa-star checked"></i></span> : testimonial.selectcontrol;
                  } else if (testimonial.selectcontrol == 'star4') {
                    return  (testimonial.selectcontrol == 'star4') ? <span><i className="fas fa-star checked"></i><i className="fas fa-star checked"></i><i className="fas fa-star checked"></i><i className="fas fa-star checked"></i></span>: testimonial.selectcontrol;
                  } else if (testimonial.selectcontrol == 'star5') {
                    return  (testimonial.selectcontrol == 'star5') ? <span><i className="fas fa-star checked"></i><i className="fas fa-star checked"></i><i className="fas fa-star checked"></i><i className="fas fa-star checked"></i><i className="fas fa-star checked"></i></span> : testimonial.selectcontrol;
                  }
                } );
```

But at the front-end its showing a string instead of the icon, probaly because i am using this:

```js
<SelectControl
  label={ __( 'Press ctrl to multiple stars:' ) }
  value={ testimonial.selectcontrol } // e.g: value = [ 'a', 'c' ]
  onChange={ (value) => handleTestimonialChange('selectcontrol', value, index ) }
  options={ [
      { value: null, label: 'Select a Star', disabled: false },
      { value: 'star',  label: 'Add 1 star' },
      { value: 'star2', label: 'Add 2 stars' },
      { value: 'star3', label: 'Add 3 stars' },
      { value: 'star4', label: 'Add 4 stars' },
      { value: 'star5', label: 'Add 5 stars' },
  ] }
/>
```

And if i am understanding it correctly, it has to show a string, because mine value is a string? Right?

So mine question is how to combine or how to make this work? So that the editor and front-end is show a star?

I hope some on could explain me this in dummy language :)

Here is mine full code for beter understanding:

```js
/**
 * BLOCK: project-drie
 *
 * Registering a basic block with Gutenberg.
 * Simple block, renders and saves the same content without any interactivity.
 */

//  Import CSS.
import './editor.scss';
import './style.scss';
import React from 'react';
import { FaStar } from "react-icons/fa";
import {Helmet} from "react-helmet";



// import components
import { useBlockProps, RichText, InnerBlocks, MediaUpload, InspectorControls, MediaUploadCheck } from '@wordpress/block-editor';


const { __ } = wp.i18n; // Import __() from wp.i18n
const { registerBlockType } = wp.blocks; // Import registerBlockType() from wp.blocks
const { Button, IconButton, PanelBody, TextareaControl, TextControl, SelectControl, CustomSelectControl } = wp.components;
const { Fragment, useState } = wp.element;


/**
 * Register: aa Gutenberg Block.
 *
 * Registers a new block provided a unique name and an object defining its
 * behavior. Once registered, the block is made editor as an option to any
 * editor interface where blocks are implemented.
 *
 * @link https://wordpress.org/gutenberg/handbook/block-api/
 * @param  {string}   name     Block name.
 * @param  {Object}   settings Block settings.
 * @return {?WPBlock}          The block, if it has been successfully
 *                             registered; otherwise `undefined`.
 */


registerBlockType( 'cgb/block-project-drie-testimonials', {
    title: __( 'project-drie - Testimonials' ), // Block title.
    icon: 'shield',
    category: 'project drie',
  supports: {
        align: true,
    },
    keywords: [
        __( 'project-drie — CGB testimonials' ),
        __( 'testimonials' ),
    __( 'testimonial' ),
    ],
  attributes: {
    title: {
      type: 'string',
      source: 'text',
      selector: 'figcaption',
    },
    subtitle: {
      type: 'string',
      source: 'text',
      selector: 'figcaption',
    },
    testimonial: {
            type: 'array',
            default: [],
        },
  },

    /**
     * The edit function describes the structure of your block in the context of the editor.
     * This represents what the editor will render when the block is used.
     *
     * The "edit" property must be a valid function.
     *
     * @link https://wordpress.org/gutenberg/handbook/block-api/block-edit-save/
     *
     * @param {Object} props Props.
     * @returns {Mixed} JSX Component.
     */


   edit: props => {
    const { attributes: {title, subtitle, testimonial, media, selectcontrol}, className, setAttributes } = props;
    const onChangeTitle = title => { setAttributes ( { title } ) };
    const onChangeSubtitle = subtitle => { setAttributes ( { subtitle } ) };
    const onSelectImage = ( media ) => { setAttributes( { media: media} );};
    const handleAddTestimonial = () => {
            const testimonial = [ ...props.attributes.testimonial ];
            testimonial.push( {
                author: '',
        position: '',
        testimonial: '',
        media: '',
        selectcontrol: '',
            } );
            props.setAttributes( { testimonial } );
        };

    const handleRemoveTestimonial = ( index ) => {
            const testimonial = [ ...props.attributes.testimonial ];
            testimonial.splice( index, 1 );
            props.setAttributes( { testimonial } );
        };

    const handleTestimonialChange = ( key, value, index  ) => {
            const testimonial = [ ...props.attributes.testimonial ];
            testimonial[ index ][key] = value;
            props.setAttributes( { testimonial } );
        };


    let testimonialFields,
            testimonialDisplay;

    let authorFields,
            authorDisplay;

    let positionFields,
            positionDisplay;

    let mediaFields,
            mediaDisplay;

    let selectcontrolFields,
            selectcontrolDisplay;


        if ( props.attributes.testimonial.length ) {
            testimonialFields = props.attributes.testimonial.map( ( testimonial, index ) => {

                return <Fragment key={ index }>
            <TextControl
                        className="author__react__testimonials"
                        placeholder="Add testimonial."
                        value={ testimonial.testimonial }
                        onChange={ ( value ) => handleTestimonialChange('testimonial', value, index ) }
                    />

            <TextControl
                        className="author__react__name"
                        placeholder="Add Author Name. Example: Ben"
                        value={ testimonial.author }
                        onChange={ ( value ) => handleTestimonialChange('author', value, index ) }
                    />

            <TextControl
                        className="author__react__name"
                        placeholder="Add Function. Example: CEO."
                        value={ testimonial.position }
                        onChange={ ( value ) => handleTestimonialChange('position', value, index ) }
                    />
            <MediaUpload
              onSelect={ (value) => handleTestimonialChange('media', value, index ) }
              allowedTypes="image"
              value={ testimonial.media.id }
              render={ ( { open } ) =>  (
                  <Button className={ testimonial.media.length > 0 ? 'image-button' : 'button button-large' } onClick={ open }>
                      { testimonial.media.length > 0 ? __( 'Upload Image', 'gutenberg-examples' ) : <img src={ testimonial.media.url } alt={ __( 'Upload Recipe Image', 'gutenberg-examples' ) } />  }
                  </Button>

              )   }
            />
            <SelectControl

              label={ __( 'Press ctrl to multiple stars:' ) }
              value={ testimonial.selectcontrol } // e.g: value = [ 'a', 'c' ]
              onChange={ (value) => handleTestimonialChange('selectcontrol', value, index ) }
              options={ [
                  { value: null, label: 'Select a Star', disabled: false },
                  { value: 'star',  label: 'Add 1 star' },
                  { value: 'star2', label: 'Add 2 stars' },
                  { value: 'star3', label: 'Add 3 stars' },
                  { value: 'star4', label: 'Add 4 stars' },
                  { value: 'star5', label: 'Add 5 stars' },
              ] }
            />

                    <IconButton
                        className="testimonials__remove__react__testimonial"
                        icon="no-alt"
                        label="Delete location"
                        onClick={ () => handleRemoveTestimonial( index ) }
                    />
                </Fragment>;
            } );

        testimonialDisplay = props.attributes.testimonial.map( ( testimonial, index ) => {
                return <p key={ index }>{ testimonial.testimonial  } </p>;
            } );

            authorDisplay = props.attributes.testimonial.map( ( testimonial, index ) => {
                return <p key={ index }>{ testimonial.author  } </p>;
            } );

        positionDisplay = props.attributes.testimonial.map( ( testimonial, index ) => {
                return <p key={ index }>{testimonial.position}</p>;
            } );

        mediaDisplay = props.attributes.testimonial.map( ( testimonial, index ) => {
          return <img key={index} src={testimonial.media.url} alt={testimonial.media.alt} />
            } );

        selectcontrolDisplay = props.attributes.testimonial.map( ( testimonial, index ) => {
          if (testimonial.selectcontrol == 'star') {
            return  (testimonial.selectcontrol == 'star') ? <span><i className="fas fa-star checked"></i></span> : testimonial.selectcontrol;
          } else if (testimonial.selectcontrol == 'star2') {
            return  (testimonial.selectcontrol == 'star2') ? <span><i className="fas fa-star checked"></i><i className="fas fa-star checked"></i></span> : testimonial.selectcontrol;
          } else if (testimonial.selectcontrol == 'star3') {
            return  (testimonial.selectcontrol == 'star3') ? <span><i className="fas fa-star checked"></i><i className="fas fa-star checked"></i><i className="fas fa-star checked"></i></span> : testimonial.selectcontrol;
          } else if (testimonial.selectcontrol == 'star4') {
            return  (testimonial.selectcontrol == 'star4') ? <span><i className="fas fa-star checked"></i><i className="fas fa-star checked"></i><i className="fas fa-star checked"></i><i className="fas fa-star checked"></i></span>: testimonial.selectcontrol;
          } else if (testimonial.selectcontrol == 'star5') {
            return  (testimonial.selectcontrol == 'star5') ? <span><i className="fas fa-star checked"></i><i className="fas fa-star checked"></i><i className="fas fa-star checked"></i><i className="fas fa-star checked"></i><i className="fas fa-star checked"></i></span> : testimonial.selectcontrol;
          }
        } );
        }

        return [
      <div className={ className }>
            <InspectorControls key="1">
                <PanelBody title={ __( 'Testimonial' ) }>
                    { testimonialFields }
                    <Button
                        isDefault
                        onClick={ handleAddTestimonial.bind( this ) }
                    >
                        { __( 'Add Testimonials' ) }
                    </Button>
                </PanelBody>
            </InspectorControls>
            <div key="2" className={ props.className }>
          <div className="wp-block-cgb-block-project-drie-testimonial-info">
            <div className="wp-block-cgb-block-project-drie-testimonial-title">
              <h2>{ __('Title', 'cgb')}</h2>
                <RichText
                  tagName="div"
                  className="wp-block-cgb-block-project-drie-testimonial-titles"
                  placeholder={ __('Add your title here', 'cgb')}
                  onChange={ onChangeTitle}
                  value={ title }
                />
            </div>
            <div className="wp-block-cgb-block-project-drie-testimonial-subtext">
            <h2>{ __('Sub-Text', 'cgb')}</h2>
              <RichText
                tagName="p"
                className="wp-block-cgb-block-project-drie-testimonial-subtexts"
                value={ subtitle }
                onChange={ onChangeSubtitle }
                placeholder={ __('Add your sub-text here', 'cgb')}
              />
            </div>
          </div>
          {testimonial.map((display, i) => (
          <div className="wp-block-cgb-block-project-drie-testimonial-repeater" key={ i }>
            <div className="wp-block-cgb-block-project-drie-testimonial-repeater-title">
                    <h2>Employee</h2>
            </div>
            <div className="wp-block-cgb-block-project-drie-testimonial-skillname">
              <h3>Author Name:</h3>
              <span>{ authorDisplay }</span>
            </div>
            <div className="wp-block-cgb-block-project-drie-testimonial-percentage">
              <h3>workFunction:</h3>
              <span>{ positionDisplay }</span>
            </div>
            <div className="wp-block-cgb-block-project-drie-testimonial-bgimages">
              <div className="wp-block-cgb-block-project-drie-testimonial-bgimage">
                <h2>Author Image</h2>
                {mediaDisplay}
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="wp-block-cgb-block-project-drie-testimonial-ratings">
              <div className="wp-block-cgb-block-project-drie-testimonial-rating">
                <h2>Rating</h2>
                {selectcontrolDisplay}
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="wp-block-cgb-block-project-drie-testimonial-testimonials">
              <div className="wp-block-cgb-block-project-drie-testimonial-testimonial">
                <h2>Review</h2>
                {testimonialDisplay}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>

        ];

    },

    /**
     * The save function defines the way in which the different attributes should be combined
     * into the final markup, which is then serialized by Gutenberg into post_content.
     *
     * The "save" property must be specified and must be a valid function.
     *
     * @link https://wordpress.org/gutenberg/handbook/block-api/block-edit-save/
     *
     * @param {Object} props Props.
     * @returns {Mixed} JSX Frontend HTML.
     */
    save: ( props ) => {
    const {attributes: { title } } = props;
    const {attributes: { subtitle } } = props;
    const {attributes: { media} } = props;
    const {attributes: { testimonial } } = props;
    const {attributes: { selectcontrol } } = props;


    // const skillnameFields = props.attributes.skillname.map( ( skillname, index ) => {
        //  return <p key={ index }>{ skillname.skill } { skillname.percentage }</p>;
        // } );

    return (
      <section className="testimonial">
        <Helmet>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/kenwheeler/slick@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
        </Helmet>
        <div className="container testimonial__container">
          <div className="row testimonial__row">
            <div className="testimonial__info">
              <div className="testimonial__subtext">
                <span>{ subtitle }</span>
              </div>
              <div className="testimonial__title">
                <h2>{ title }</h2>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="items testimonial__testimonials">
              {testimonial.map((field, i) => (
              <div className="testimonial__testimonial">
                <div className="testimonial__card" key={ i }>
                  <div className="testimonial__image">
                    <img src={field.media.url} />
                  </div>
                  <div className="testimonial__review">
                    <p>{field.testimonial}</p>
                  </div>
                  <div className="testimonial__stars">
                    <span>{field.selectcontrol}</span>
                  </div>
                  <div className="testimonial__author">
                    <div className="testimonial__name">
                      <span>{ field.author }</span>
                    </div>
                    <div className="testimonial__function">
                      <span>{ field.position }</span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              ))}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    );
    },
 } );
```

Answer (score 0):

After importing icon you just need to write

```
<FaStar/>
```

instead of

```
<i className="fas fa-star checked">
```

Comment: hello, still getting a string at the front end. In the editor side everything is working fine.

The problem is i think: `<SelectControl />` and `<div className="testimonial__stars">
                    <span>{field.selectcontrol}</span>
                  </div>`